# Splitting a string with two different characters

Tags: python, regex, split

I have the following string

```
u'root\n |-- date: string (nullable = true)\n |-- zip: string (nullable = true)\n'
```

I would like to extract the column names. The column names have `|--` before them and `:` after them.

I could do this in two stages:

```
s = u'root\n |-- date: string (nullable = true)\n |-- zip: string (nullable = true)\n' 
s = s.split('|-- ')
s = s.split(':')
```

However, I wanted to know if there is a way to split with two characters at once.

Comment: if you need just the names just use findall, you are doing unnecessary work splitting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, I wanted to know if there is a way to split with two characters at once.

It is possible using [`re#split`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.split):

```
re.split(r'\|--|:', your_string)
```

Comment: why use split when the OP wants the extract just the names?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that was his original question: "I wanted to know if **there is a way to split with two characters at once**."

Comment: yes using `str.split` not `re.split`, they were attempting to split and access the words

Comment: @PadraicCunningham he wanted to "split".. Didn't mention what split method is desired..

Comment: **I would like to extract the column names. The column names have |-- before them and : after them.**

Comment: Let us let him decide, will edit my answer if it doesn't help OP.

Comment: neat thing though! +1

Comment: I do just want the names, but my current situation got me thinking of this in a more general way. In my case, maybe just splitting won't help me as much since then I will lose the names. I do only need the characters between the two symbol combinations.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to get them both at once:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = u'root\n |-- date: string (nullable = true)\n |-- zip: string (nullable = true)\n'
>>> re.findall(r'\|--\s(\w+):', data)
['date', 'zip']
>>>
```

Below is an explanation of the Regex pattern used:

```
\|--   # Matches |--
\s     # Matches a whitespace character
(\w+)  # Capture group for one or more word characters
:      # Matches :
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `findall` instead of splitting if you only want the names splitting and then extracting will be less efficient than just using findall:

So based on *I would like to extract the column names. The column names have |-- before them and : after them.*

```
import re

s = u'root\n |-- date: string (nullable = true)\n |-- zip: string (nullable = true)\n'
print(re.findall(r"\|--\s+(.*?):",s))
['date', 'zip']
```

Or use [re.compile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile):

```
patt = re.compile(r"\|--\s+(.*?):")
patt.findall(s)
['date', 'zip']
```

It is not possible to split using two delimiters `str.split`.

If you were to use `str.split` you could do something like:

```
print([x.split(":")[0] for x in s.split("|-- ")[1:]])
['date', 'zip']
```

After the initial split the first elements in sub splits will always be the element with `:` but this approach would break if you have any other `|--` elsewhere that is not surrounding data you want.

Comment: Your approach solves my problem. I suppose I should have phrased my question differently

Comment: @Michal, it seemed pretty obvious to me that you wanted to just get the names I  presumed split only really came into the equation because you had tried str.split which is an understandable approach.